# I'm a graphic designer freelancer. Do I give the finished work to client before or after they paid me?

Tags: price

I am a freelancing graphic designer and I just received a new client (via the internet) who wants me to edit some photographs. We will be using PayPal to transfer the payment, but I was wondering if I should collect the payment before or after I send the final product online?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Welcome to the Freelancing Stack Exchange site! Unfortunately, you've already asked this question here: [I'm a freelancer. Do I give the finished work to client before or after they paid me?](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2517/im-a-freelancer-do-i-give-the-finished-work-to-client-before-or-after-they-pai). The proper way to handle this is to [edit](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/posts/2517/edit) the old question, which automatically flags it for possible reopening. Posting the same question multiple times is bad form.

Answer (score 2):

It is customary, especially for new clients, to ask for an upfront deposit, then the bulk of payment upon delivery.For random internet clients I **always** ask for an upfront **non-refundable** deposit.

If it is a larger projects, I ask for 33% up front. Then another 33% upon delivery of mockups. Then the remaining 33% upon delivery of the work.

If it's a smaller project, I ask for 50% up front, then the remaining 50% upon completion.

This way, if you do get ripped off, you only lose part of the project revenue and not all of it.

Ultimately **there are no rules for this**. It's merely a matter of how **you** wish to handle it. You should also be *very careful* posting the same question just a few moments after your original question has been put on hold. Had I seen the duplicate I would not have answered this. Continually posting like that could result in your account being suspended.